# Changing the size of a button widget in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I can't seem to resize a button I'm trying to make on tkinter, this is my first time using tkinter so I don't know too much, is this how it is meant to be done or is there a better or easier way? Whenever i try to run the code it says tkinter.tclerror unknown option "-height", the code I'm using is below. Thanks

```
from tkinter.ttk import *
...
myButton = Button(gui, text="Continue", height = 100, width = 100)
myButton.grid(row=10, column=2)
```

Comment: I think you are using `ttk.Button` instead of `tkinter.Button`.  Did you have a line `from tkinter.ttk import *` after `from tkinter import *` in your code?

Comment: Hi, yeah I have 'from tkinter.ttk import *' just under 'from tkinter import *'

Comment: Just make it `from tkinter import *` It'll work fine

Comment: This way of importing modules is not recommended.  Change them to `import tkinter as tk` and `import tkinter.ttk as ttk`.  Then use `tk.Button(...)` instead of `Button(...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you use the `ttk.Button` instead of `tkinter.Button` (`ttk` one doesn't have `height` and `width` parameters).

I have written an example for you.

**Code:**

```
import tkinter as tk  # Should use the tkinter module

root = tk.Tk()

original = tk.Button(root, text="Original")
original.grid(row=1, column=1)

resized = tk.Button(root, text="Resized", height=20, width=20)
resized.grid(row=2, column=1)

tk.mainloop()
```

**GUI:**

[image: GUI Result]

**Note:**

Here is a `ttk.Button` resizing related SO question: [Changing ttk Button Height in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9927386/changing-ttk-button-height-in-python)

Comment: Thanks for all the help!